# How should you model objects that change with the passage of time

Tags: database-design, activerecord, uml, data-modeling, erd

I'm trying to develop a data/object model for passengers who take trips on planes.
In words:

```
we have customers who make reservations to take trips.
```

I'm having difficulty determining if I should have two objects/models: Customer and Trip or three: Customer, Reservation and Trip.

I believe my confusion stems from the fact that as time passes a reservation morphs into a trip. This fact leads me to think it would be best to have just two models: Customer and Trip. Under this scenario the Trip would belong to customer, and would have the following sample attributes: customer_id, reservation_number, destination, travel_date, etc.

The problem I have with this approach is that reservation change and are cancelled and I'm a bit reluctant to muddle the Trip model with a lot of changes in travel date, destinations or cancellations.

Update:  Here's a little more on Trip (Flight)
Items of interest:  number of passengers, depart time, landing time, duration of flight, number of cancellations, destination, miles traveled, cost of a ticket, on-time arrival flag, weather conditions.  trip/flight can be cancelled by the airline, weather and reservations can be cancelled by customer right up to trip/flight time.

Perhaps what I am missing is a forth model that transitions a reservation to a trip (ticket?).

So my question(s).

1. Is the problem that I describe a particular class of data model with a preferred design pattern, if so, what is the pattern and solution.
2. How have others with more experienced than me solved this problem.

I happen to be using ruby on rails / activerecord for development, but the question applies to any development framework.

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a customer has_many trips and a trip has_many customers which is a many_to_many relationship.

```
models/customer.rb
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reservations
  has_many :trips, :through => :reservations
end

models/trip.rb
class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reservations
  has_many :customers, :through => :reservations
end

models/reservation.rb
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :trip
end
```

Reservations and tickets seem like the same thing to me, so I don't think you need a separate `Ticket` model.

Comment: Powers that for the great reply, my only question is there something missing.  To me there seems to be a point in time where a reservation either turns into a trip or is cancelled or change.  This is the piece that seems to be missing. How is this captured or am I making this this up in my head.

Comment: But a reservation can be cancelled in which case a ticket is never issued, yes?

Comment: The `Reservation` model can have a ticket field to indicate the ticket status.  If there is complex ticket stuff that is different from reservation stuff, then a separate model may be justified, but based on the facts I have seen, the seem pretty similar.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend creating a [domain model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_model) first and ignoring implementation all together. The persistence mechanism and programming environment will become relevant when you have completed the [domain model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_model) and your ready to begin development.

Comment: Point taken, but I think I would have the same question as a built my domain model.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree. I think you'll have a much better understanding of the problem domain by beginning with a conceptual model. You can iterate over it has you think of all the possible scenarios and relationships in the problem space. A good domain model can be translated into a data model later.

Answer (score 1):

In a such system it is usually better to have a clear separation between the *Reservation* entity and the *Trip* entity. Answering these questions could help you to design your system:

- Is a trip can exist before any reservation (in a catalog for example)?
- Is a trip can be shared by many reservations?

If you answer 'yes' to theses questions you cloud imagine a design like that:

[Trip UML Class diagram http://app.genmymodel.com/engine/xaelis/trip.jpg](http://app.genmymodel.com/engine/xaelis/trip.jpg)

You can make a copy and adapt the model with this [link](http://app.genmymodel.com/genmymodel?clonedProject=_DIdl0N9xEDCxlLZ25-stbw).

Answer (score 1):

Ask yourself two questions:

1. What do you need to know about trips?  What can you do to a trip?
2. As above for reservations

Reservations is probably more obvious: who made the reservation (association with Customer), when it was made, has it been paid for/cancelled/whatever.

Trip is less clear.  Are trips organised events that have e.g. start/end dates?  Does each trip have a maximum capacity (i.e. max number of bookings?).  Does each trip have a price? Can multiple people book on the same trip?  Can a trip be cancelled?  Is cancelling a trip different from cancelling a reservation?  What happens to bookings if a trip is cancelled?

Secondly, how would you describe what happens if/when a reservation 'transitions' into a trip.  Are you really just saying that the Customer took the trip?  If it transitions, do you still care about all the reservation info you captured?

Gut feeling says Trip and Reservation are different things.  Perhaps the "transition" is actually a missing relationship between Customer and Trip that records when the Customer actually took the trip.

It will depend on being clear on the questions above.

hth.

Comment: For these purposes let's assume Trip is a flight.  I'd be interested in number of passengers, depart time, landing time, duration of flight, number of cancellations, destination, miles traveled, cost of a ticket, on-time arrival flag, weather conditions.

Comment: @Mutuelinvestor: then I think you just answered your own question :-).  Actually, you probably have three classes here.  One for the Flight Schedule: scheduled departure/arrival time, cost, miles travelled.  It represents many flights.  One for the actual flight which captures date, actual departure/arrival times, weather. And one for the reservation as above.  The link from Flight to reservation is how you'd determine cancellations (select all related Reservations where status = cancelled).